# How to Parse XML - Complex XML Construction in Swift 3

Tags: swift, xml, parsing

I have to parse xml file in my application. I get xml data from web service with token. I can not parse true xml tag's data because xml file is a complex construction and a few tags repeat a few times. For example xml file has 17 "cbc:ID" tag. I need first cbc:ID tag which into "invoice" tag.   [This an example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uBlYerlRfTNXDWveLfDGLAK3lxxHzXNr) for my xml data. I use that function;

```
func getXMLDataFromServer(authorization:String){
        let url = NSURL(string: self.urlString)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue(authorization, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data,response,error in

            if error != nil {
                //print("\(error)")
            }

            else {

                let htmlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                //print("\(htmlContent)")

            }
            if let receivedData = data {
                if let aString = String(data: receivedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                    if let percentage = aString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:CharacterSet(charactersIn:"ıİöÖçÇüÜğĞşŞ").inverted) {
                        if let aData = percentage.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                            let parser = XMLParser(data: aData)
                            parser.delegate = self
                            parser.parse()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

> ```
> //MARK:- XML Delegate methods
> func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?,
> ```
>
> attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
>           currentParsingElement = elementName
>           if elementName == "Invoice" {
>               print("Started parsing...")
>           }
>           print(elementName)
>       }
>
> ```
> func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
>     let foundedChar = string.trimmingCharacters(in:NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
>
>     if (!foundedChar.isEmpty) {
>         if currentParsingElement == "cbc:ID" {
>             ipAddr += foundedChar
>         }
>         else if currentParsingElement == "cbc:Name" {
>             countryCode += foundedChar
>         }
>         else if currentParsingElement == "CountryName" {
>             countryName += foundedChar
>         }
>
>     }
>     print(foundedChar)
> }
>
> func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
>     if elementName == "Invoice" {
>         print("Ended parsing...")
>     }
>
>     print(elementName)
>
> }
>
> func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {
>     DispatchQueue.main.async {
>         // Update UI
>         //self.displayOnUI()
>
>     }
> }
>
> func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: Error) {
>     print("parseErrorOccurred: \(parseError)")
> }
> ```

I have tried [that tutorial](https://insights.nimblechapps.com/app-development/ios-app-development/parsing-xml-web-service-ios-swift) for parse my xml data. However I can not parse true tag in my xml data.

I need some tag's datas there are "cbc:ID" tag's data in "invoice" tag,
"cbc:Name" tag's data in "cac:AccountingCustomerParty" tag, 
again "cbc:ID" tag but it is into "cac:AccountingCustomerParty" 
and "cbc:PayableAmount" tag's data in "cac:LegalMonetaryTotal"

Someone have an idea how to parse true tag's data for my application?

Comment: 1. Upate your question with the text (no picture) of the relevant XML (not all of it, just a relevant, representative section of it). 2. Update your question with your attempted XML parsing code (your XMLParserDelegate methods).

Comment: @rmaddy I edited my xml parsing method but i didnt add xml example because its huge but i gave a link. However if you want i can add my xml example

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code. Remove the `>` on each line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing a so complex XML with `XMLParser` is realy hard.

If you don't mind using an external library, you can try [XMLMapper](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper).

Actually this is easy using the nested mapping. You can have the following model classes:

```
class Invoice: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var cbcID: String?
    var partyName: String?
    var partyCBCID: PartyCBCID?
    var payableAmount: PayableAmount?

    required init?(map: XMLMap) { }

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        cbcID <- map["cbc:ID"]
        partyName <- map["cac:AccountingCustomerParty.cac:Party.cac:PartyName.cbc:Name"]
        partyCBCID <- map["cac:AccountingCustomerParty.cac:Party.cac:PartyIdentification.cbc:ID"]
        payableAmount <- map["cac:LegalMonetaryTotal.cbc:PayableAmount"]
    }

}

class PartyCBCID: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var schemeID: String?
    var id: String?

    required init?(map: XMLMap) { }

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        schemeID <- map.attributes["schemeID"]
        id <- map.innerText
    }

}

class PayableAmount: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var currencyID: String?
    var amount: Double?

    required init?(map: XMLMap) { }

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        currencyID <- map.attributes["currencyID"]
        amount <- map.innerText
    }
}
```

and you can map your XML string using `map(XMLString:)` function of `XMLMapper` like:

```
let invoice = XMLMapper<Invoice>().map(XMLString: xmlString)
print(invoice?.cbcID ?? "nil") // access cbc:ID for example
```

Try it out.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I didn't use second party solution before actually  i cannot how can i use that example i'm going to try today. I hope i can deal with it. Thank yo again.